# Xcode 5 with iOS 5 issue on storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

xcode 5 can't update view on storyboard after changing the deployment target iOS5. I was also remove the arm64 but still it won't updated on simulator here i attached my screenshot.

please tell me anybody face same fix and how fixing that.

Thanks

1. [image: 1.]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. Output - on simulator doesn't change the `UIButton` Text also

[image]

6. When i trying to uncheck base localization it show like below,

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about user error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up the storyboard because i'm newly working on this. The solution is it created twice one is base version another one is English

[image]

Comment: yes! selecting main and unchecking base will delete one automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the Base on the right side under Localization and keep only English. Do not know why, but it did work for me.

Comment: i can't uncheck the base mode. how it does

Comment: when i trying to uncheck for base localization it show warning like  "There is a localization operation in progress"

Comment: keep selected them main storyboard not any nib inside and then go inside the file inspector then uncheck it.

Comment: Restart the xcode, keep selected the main storyboard not any nib inside the storyboard and then go inside the file inspector then uncheck it. Yes it also took more than one tries for me to do this

Comment: thanks i got solution...